# Create parameters in API Header in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I have created a API in WSO2 studio integrator like below:

curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8290/internal/send-messages' 
--header 'accept: text/plain' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data-raw '{
"bankName": "heere",
"uniqueIdentifier": "445334564"
}'

To pass the requests (which received from this API) toward the endpoint, I need to add two following parameters into API Header

--header 'MasterName: TOMSON' 
--header 'clientName: TOM' \

TOMSON value is unique(static) and would NOT change for any user.
However TOM would be change based on application username given from API Manager (there is OATH2 authentication).

1. How can I add a static header (Like MasterName) to a API while sending toward the endpoint
2. How can I understand the username of application ??

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add a static header using the header mediator[1].
   `<header name="MasterName" value="TOMSON" scope="transport"/>`
2. To get the application information from the API Manager, you can enable backend JWT[2]. This will be a JWT generated with much more information regarding the request. By decoding this[3] JWT at the backend, you can get the application information with the claim `http://wso2.org/claims/applicationname`.

[1] - https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/header-Mediator/
[2] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/passing-enduser-attributes-to-the-backend-via-api-gateway/
[3] - [WSO2 Decode JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68107784/wso2-decode-jwt)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [header mediator](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/mediators/header-mediator/)  to add headers

For example

```xml
<header name="miCustomHeader" value="ThisIsTheWay" scope="transport"/>

<send>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="https://someRandomURL"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

It will send *miCustomHeader* along its value to the endpoint